# Use output of command as exit code

Tags: bash, git, exit-code

For my Continuous Integration scripts I want to check if the git branch is not in sync with the master branch. Therefore I use

```
git rev-list --left-right --count master...my-branch-name
```

It will return sth. like

```
1    3
```

(3 commits ahead of master, 1 behind)

Adding `| cut -f1` will give me only the first number (commits behind master).

Now I want to exit the script just with that number because 0 commits behind is success, all other should give an error.

How can I do that? I tried

```
exit 'git rev-list --left-right --count master...my-branch-name | cut -f1'
```

but this raises

> /bin/bash: line 66: exit: git rev-list --left-right --count master...my-branch-name | cut -f1: numeric argument required

Is there a best practice for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply change your line:

```
exit 'git rev-list --left-right --count master...my-branch-name | cut -f1'
```

to:

```
exit `git rev-list --left-right --count master...my-branch-name | cut -f1`
```

Anything between the `` ` `` quotation marks will be executed and returned to the bash script, so you can do whatever you want with it, including assigning it to a variable.

Comment: Use `$(...)` instead of backticks: much easier to see the difference.

Comment: Possibly yes, the way I wrote is the historical compatibility way of doing it, the `$(...)` way is newer and supposedly more "compatible" between different shells, but both should work with no issues in bash.

Comment: backticks are OK for bash, but bad for humans. It took me several seconds to spot the difference in your answer.

Comment: Backticks are also harder to nest.